# Alternative method of converting a linear problem into standard form LP

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming

The **problem** we are given is:

\begin{align}
& \text{Find a vector} && \mathbf{x} \\
& \text{that maximizes}   && \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x}\\
& \text{subject to} && W \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\pi} \\
& \text{and} && \mathbf{x} \ge \mathbf{0}.
\end{align} 
Where $W$ is an $N$ by $M$ matrix.

And we want to convert it into a standard [LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (linear program)

\begin{align}
& \text{Find a vector} && \mathbf{x} \\
& \text{that maximizes}   && \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x}\\
& \text{subject to} && A \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b} \\
& \text{and} && \mathbf{x} \ge \mathbf{0}.
\end{align}

The textbook way of doing this would be replacing the contraint $W \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\pi}$, by the constraints $W \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{\pi}$ **and** $-W \mathbf{x} \leq -\mathbf{\pi}$, and stacking these two inequalities on top of each other.

**Question**:
Is there a way of converting this problem into an LP without using this trick?

**My attempt**:
Replace the constraint $W \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\pi}$, by the constraint $W \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{\pi}$ and the additional maximization condition $\text{max}(W\mathbf{q})$. Unfortunately, these are now $N+1$ maximization problems, instead of one (because $W$ is a matrix).

Comment: ok, but why tho

Comment: Excellent question @KaragounisZ, I am developing an algorithm that will run on quantum computers. Using the conventional textbook method makes it computationally unstable, unfortunately, so I need to find another way.

Comment: what if you put the equality constraint into the objective function as in the Lagrangian relaxation?
For instance, your optimization problem has value equal to $\max_{x \geq 0} \min_\lambda \{D'x - \lambda \cdot (Wx - \pi)\}$

Comment: Thank you @KaragounisZ. The solution that you provided isn't a standard LP form? Is there an easy way of converting this into a standard LP form?

Comment: Have you tried looking at a possible asymmetric dual formulation of your LP?